# How can I access a variable in a class which is imported by main page?

Tags: php

I was searching for a way to access a variable in a function from the other function in the same class. What I searched is using global variable. It works well when I created methods and printing codes on the same page(and not a class), but when I separate those methods in a class and call them from main page, it didn't work.

oh..and I just found that I can't use global variable because I the $rand_type should be different every time i_type() method iterates in a table, on a main page. And I need to use the same value of $rand_type in both methods.

(The situation is... in my game, I'm going to randomly print different types of items first, then click one of them to determine the class and level randomly.)

How can I solve it?

```
class Item {

    function i_type() {
        $rand_type = rand(1,8);
        // some other codes below..
        return $some_data;
    }

    function i_buy() {

        $rand_class = rand(1,3);
        $rand_level = rand(1,5);
        // some other codes below..
        return $some_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: `class Item { private $rand_level; function foo(){ $this->rand_level ...`

Comment: A function to return a private/protected variable is silly, just make it public if you need to access it, saves creating a redundant method

Answer (score 1):

You set `private` or `public` variables (private is safer but restricted access).

```
class Item {
    private $rand_class;
    private $rand_level;
    function getRandLevel() {
        return $this->rand_level;
    }
    function setRandLevel($param) {
        //clean variable before setting value if needed
        $this->rand_level = $param;
    }
}
```

Then you call any function after making an instance of the class

```
$class = new Item();
$rand_level = $class->getRandLevel();
$setlvl = 5;
$class->setRandLevel($setlvl);
```

This is called encapsulation. But that is a higher concept. private/public variables are access like that.

Comment: Obviously these aren't your methods, but it can help future assignments/projects and it's easy to manipulate your class to use this concept

Answer (score 0):

You can access variable by :

- Making it public
- Getters

  ```
  class Item {

  private $rand_type;
  private $rand_class; 
  private $and_level;

  public function setRandType($type){  $this->rand_type =$type ;}

  public function getRandType(){ return $this->rand_type ;}


  public function i_type() {
      $this->rand_type = rand(1,8);
      // some other codes below..
      return $some_data;
  }

  public function i_buy() {

      $this->rand_class = rand(1,3);
      $this->rand_level = rand(1,5)
      // some other codes below..
      return $some_data;
  }

    }
  ```

So you instantiate your object :

```
 $item = new Item();
```

When you call  `$item->i_type()` and then `$item->getRandType()` you will get the rand value from `i_buy()`.